# how to dynamically get values from Input and Radio buttons, push them to an array and call them for various calculations

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to dynamically get the value from an Input field(`amount`) and a Radio button(`tType`) and push them into an array in the format `(amount,date,tType)`.  Then I want to do two things with the array :1.  Get all the amounts and add them up to get the total. 2. List all the data in the array. Here is what i have:

```
   var Transaction = function(amount) {
        this.amount = amount
        this.date = (function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var minutes = d.getMinutes();
            var month = d.getMonth() +1;
            if (minutes<10) {
                return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + "0" + minutes);
            } else {
                return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + minutes);
            }
        })();


    var radios = document.getElementsByName('tType');

    for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            // do whatever you want with the checked radio
            return(radios[i].value);

            // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
            break;
        }
    }
        this.type= radios;
    };
    var movements =[];
    var allAmounts = [];

    function clearFields(){ 
            document.getElementById("initialAmount").value="";
            document.getElementById("amountIn").value="";
            document.getElementById("amountOut").value="";
         };

    //addInitialBalance
    function addInitialBalance(){
    var a = Number(document.getElementById("initialAmount").value);
    var initialBalance = new Transaction(a);
    movements.unshift([initialBalance.amount,initialBalance.date,initialBalance.type]);
    }
    //add IN
    function addIn(){
    var aI = Number(document.getElementById("amountIn").value);
    var aIn = new Transaction(aI);
    movements.push([aIn.amount,aIn.date, aIn.type]);
    }
    //add OUT
    function addOut(){
    var aO = Number(document.getElementById("amountOut").value);
    var aOut = new Transaction(-aO);
    movements.push([aOut.amount, aOut.date, aOut.type]);
    }

    //display movements
    function list(){
        var html=" "
        for(var i in movements){
        html+=("<p>" + movements[i][0]+ " " + movements[i][1] + " " + movements[i][2] + "</p>")}
        document.getElementById("listSpace").innerHTML = html;
    }

    //get the total

    function getTotal(){
        for(var j in movements){
            allAmounts.push(movements[j][0]);
        }
        var total = (allAmounts.reduce(function(a,b){
            return a+b ; 
            },0));
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = ("Your current balance is " +total);
    }
```

Here is my html related to calling and displaying the getTotal() and list() function

```
      <div data-role="content" >
          <span id="total" style="text-align:center"></span>
      </div>

      <p style="text-align: center;" >
              <b style="margin-top:10%" onClick="getTotal()"><button>Calculate</button>
              </b>
      </p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible-set">
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" onClick="list()">
              <h3>
                  10 Last movements
              </h3>
              <div data-controltype="textblock"><span id="listSpace"> </span>


              </div>
```

Cant figure out what I am doing wrong.  When I press the `calculate` button nothing happens same with the `collapsible onClick`.  Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: `getTotal()` uses the `movements` array.  But, it's not clear how any of the other functions in your code get called that actually put anything into the `movements` array.  So, if this is your code, then `getTotal()` will get called and `movements` will be empty so it won't have much to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 The 'addInitialBalance()' 'addIn()' and 'addOut()' functions get called by other buttons in my html. still shouldn't the getTotal() function write the innerHTML statement with 0 as the total?

Comment: Not if you have an error somewhere stopping it from running.  Have you looked in the error console or debug console for script errors?  Also, you should NEVER iterate over arrays with `for (x in array)` syntax.  That iterates over object properties (in no particular order), not just array elements.  Sometimes that is the same list, sometimes not.